# How to disable tracing in windows cmd

Tags: console, trace

When I run commands in the Windows CMD terminal I see a lot of tracing information.
I have not specifically done anything to enable it.
After some commands (not all) - for example, dotnet. I get this message

```
Tracing enabled @ Tue Mar 30 16:34:45 2021 GMT
--- Invoked dotnet [version: 5.0.4, commit hash: f27d33729518f5aa478aa818b7b4f54a4d50bef1] main = {
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
}
```

for PowerShell I see similar

```
Tracing enabled @ Tue Mar 30 15:29:02 2021 GMT
--- Invoked apphost [version: 5.0.4, commit hash: f27d33729518f5aa478aa818b7b4f54a4d50bef1] main = {
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe
-WorkingDirectory
~
}
```

the question is how to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change environment variable

COREHOST_TRACE=0

Not sure how it was changed on my computer :(.